# @ORM\Id does not make an identifier for an entity in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, mapping, symfony-3.2

I hava a class City which consists of a number of traits.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="City")
 * @SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 */
class City
{
    use IdentifiableEntity;
    use TimestampableEntity;    
}
```

I have a trait IdentifiableEntity

```
trait IdentifiableEntity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    //setter getter
}
```

the problem occurs when I execute **bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff** I get this error message

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                                         
  No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "AppBundle\Entity\City\City". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.
```

Why is that? I have clearly stated in my trait that `$id` should be treated like `@ORM\Id`. Adding `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")` does not help either. What's wrong?

P.S. I am using symfony 3.2 and doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle: 1.0

Comment: any chance you have another entity, with an association pointing to this 'City' entity, which is pointing to the wrong namespace ?? (AppBundle\Entity\City\City) <- double city

Comment: @SamJanssens, exactly, but it is the right namespace to point to this entity.

Comment: it seems that it is not possible to make a primary key inside of a trait. Strangely I struggle to find any info about it

Comment: I assume you've got use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM; within your trait entity?

Comment: @Doug yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still cares.

No, it's not possible to have a field in a trait, where these are having configuration or mapped fields
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/3.1/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#using-traits-in-entity-classes

Answer (score 0):

This is possible only if your class City has other $id property without annotaion. So it overrides $id from trait.
Otherwise make sure this is the exact City class, not some other from another namespace.

Comment: not quite sure I understood the second part, so I ask again: you say I have to override an $id every time from a trait in order to make it work?

Comment: What he means is your City entity must have an $id attribute, and this $id attribute will be overriden by the one from your trait. If the only purpose of your trait is to have an $id attribute as primary key on all your entity, you should avoid using it

Comment: I mean if you what to get an id exactly from trait, make sure you dont have an id inside the City class. Because an id from City class will be in priority for doctrine and than from trait.

Comment: @ArturYukhatov I don't have another id apart from the one from trait. So I think it is just not possible for doctrine to use traits primary key as primary key for a entity which uses the trait.

Comment: @OlivierC that's bad, to have a trait which sets primary key for an entity which uses it looks nice

Comment: @user7808407 It is possible. Than make sure you dont have mess ups with namespaces and class names. Maybe you have other City class?

Comment: it IS possible, and it does NOT require an extra id property inside the class, i just checked in one of my projects